# jtable - autoresizable and manually resizable at the same time?

Tags: swing, jtable

If I'm using `table.setAutoResizeMode` method to make table autoresizable, then it is not possible to resize it by hand (make wider than window for example).
But it should be possible to adjust table width "manually", for the case, when text in cell wider than window. From other hand I want a table to be autoresizable for better usability. How to have both?